# Kurtosis and Skewness issues with a repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: statistics

I am a psychology graduate student doing my results for my masters thesis. I ran into an issues with kurtosis (over 2) and skewness (over 3) for several of my pretest measures. I used a mood questionnaire with 20 questions and 2 subscales. I was looking at each question individually to detect for significant effects. I had two groups and had participants take the questionnaire twice. An important note is that I am using SPSS for my data analyses. I am unsure if I should be running a whole different test or if I should just be looking for certain pieces of information from a repeated measures ANOVA.

Comment: Seems like you need to collect more data.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data does not seem to follow a Normal distribution, I suggest that you use the [Friedman test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test).